# Intermittent Java PostgreSQL Connection closed

Tags: java, postgresql, ibatis

My Java program connects using ibatis to a PostgreSQL DB server. Most of the time, the connection is fine.

However, sometimes the connection takes very long and then I get an exception stating that the connection has been closed, although I have not closed it at all.
Yet later on my program still can access the DB server normally.

The stack trace is here.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:822)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.rollback(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:839)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource$SimplePooledConnection.invoke(SimpleDataSource.java:958)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.rollback(Unknown Source)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.rollback(JdbcTransaction.java:72)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.TransactionManager.end(TransactionManager.java:87)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.endTransaction(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:734)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.endTransaction(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:176)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.endTransaction(SqlMapClientImpl.java:153)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.autoEndTransaction(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:835)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.insert(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:410)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.insert(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:82)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.insert(SqlMapClientImpl.java:58)
at mblib.dao.TrxLogDAO.insertLog(TrxLogDAO.java:32)
... 10 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the PostgreSQL server error log for more detail.

Comment: @CraigRinger the log simply says "could not receive data from client: Connection timed out"

Comment: You have network issues then. Maybe a NAT router connection table timing out? That sort of thing. TCP keepalives may help, depending on the nature of the problem.